# Index multiple matrix and multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula for extracting the values from *Column B* from the specified text on *Column A* that matches the cell E1. I want to do the same with *Column C* and *D* in the same formula and column (as shown in the *F column*). I also don't want to get repeated values (colored in red). How do I do that?

I've tried with thousand variations of this, but I didn't get results

```
{=INDEX(B:B;SMALL(A:A=E2;ROW());ROW())}
```

**Screen shot:**

![sample][1]

[[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9BVx.png][1]

Comment: Look I've posted the solution on the basis of screen shot which was attached with OP. But you have made twist,, and attached the new Screen shot,, :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is the solution, based on the recent Screen shot you have uploaded.*

[image]

The Formula I've used is in **Cell N15**,

```
{=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($J$15:$J$31, MATCH(0, IF($L$13=$I$15:$I$31, COUNTIF($N$15:$N15, $J$15:$J$31), ""), 0)), INDEX($L$15:$L$31, MATCH(0, IF($L$13=$K$15:$K$31, COUNTIF($N$15:$N15, $L$15:$L$31), ""), 0))),"")}
```

**Data Range is I15:L31.**

*Criteria is in Cell L13.*

**NB:** It's CSE Formula, extracts unique values from 2 Columns, filters on the Criteria.

Comment: Glad to help you @Santos Lee ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

Check this Screen shot,

[image]

Formula I've used is **Cell N1**, =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(M$1,I1:L12,{2,4},FALSE),"")

Criteria is in **Cell M1** in Green colour.

Output is in Red colour.

**NB:** Drag the Formula 2 Columns right then down till Row 12.

**Hope this help you, I've posted this solution after it was tested by me.**

Comment: thank you, but i was looking for a formula (array) in the same column, with no repeated values

Comment: I've had created the solution according to the data arrangements shown by you and you have never mentioned that you are looking for Unique value!!

Comment: im sorry but your formula doesnt even work. Put an "A" on the cell A12 and see what happens. And also i have put "i dont want to get repeated values", i didnt modified that

Comment: May be you are unable to handle the Formula properly, otherwise my Screen Shot is an evidence that it's working. And my post is based on OP, after that you have altered the OP!!